# HTML: How to make mid-row text line up the same as other rows like "tabs"

Tags: css, tabs, html-email

I am trying to build an HTML signature file and want the phone numbers and such to line up.

Phone: (234) 567-8910
Cell:      (234) 567-8910
Fax:       (234) 567-8910
Email:  mike@example.com

I can do different sized margins or number of &nbsp; for each line but that doesn't display the same on all email clients/web browsers.

```
    Phone: <span style="margin-left:12px;"><?=$phone ?></span><br/>
    Cell: <span style="margin-left:23px;"><?=$cell ?></span><br/>
    Fax: <span style="margin-left:25px;"><?=$fax ?></span><br/>
    Email: <span style="margin-left:14px;"><?=$email ?></span><br/>
```

With tables depreciated I don't want to rely on using one.

Also it's for an email signature so it has to be able to be displayed in outlook (which doesn't accept margin- or float among other things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might get grilled for not listening to your question properly, but I think it's important that you realize that tables are not completely depreciated, but rather depreciated when relying on one for something other than tabular data.

In your case, your data **is** tabular. You have a column on the left specifying content types, and a column on the right specifying values.

Thus, in this usage case, **the use of tables is perfectly acceptable**, and is actually what tables are designed for. Thus, it would actually make *less* sense to use tabs, spaces, or padding here, because there is already an HTML structure designed for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use a definition list:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Phone</dt>
    <dd>Some number</dd>
    <dt>Cell</dt>
    <dd>Some mobile number</dd>
    <dt>Fax</dt>
    <dd>Seriously, a fax?</dd>
    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>An email address</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

dt,dd {
    display: inline-block;
    /* or you could use:
    float: left;
    */
}

dt {
    width: 30%;
}

dd {
    width: 65%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo, using `display: inline-block;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m8X2h/).

[JS Fiddle demo, using `float: left;`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m8X2h/1/).

Comment: Our users aren't tech savy enough to make their own signatures so yes seriously a fax :D

Comment: unfortunately outlook doesn't support {display: inline-block;} or {float: left;} so I'll have to do table.

Comment: Ah...somehow I managed to miss the email requirement (it's late, and so on...sorry =/ ), if you're working on email the easiest thing to do is pretend the last fifteen years of web-development, and best-practices, never happened...

Comment: @Mike: while I thank you for the accept, this answer doesn't solve your problem, whereas I think that [@BraedenP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590391/html-how-to-make-mid-row-text-line-up-the-same-as-other-rows-like-tabs/7590440#7590440)'s answer does. Or at least guides you in the right direction. My answer is useful for general web-design, but for email clients not so much. Certainly if you require Outlook compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, I'll cahnge it and edit my original question to include mentioning Outlook (though it's the clients our customer use that matter, most of them will be using outlook express or windows mail I think).